# Heat map on Basemap\RuntimeError matplotlib-basemap

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I made heat map on basemap like this and evrything work well, but i want to add else label with number of occurrences, and i get: `RuntimeError: No mappable was found to use for colorbar creation. First define a mappable such as an image (with imshow) or a contour set (with contourf).`
How to do it correctly ?

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Piotr\Desktop\Meteorite_Landings1.csv")

df = df.dropna()

lat = df['reclat'].values
lon = df['reclong'].values 

m = Basemap(projection = 'mill',
           llcrnrlat = -90,
           urcrnrlat = 90,
           llcrnrlon = -180,
           urcrnrlon = 180,
           resolution = 'c')

m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90, 90,10), labels=[True, False, False, False])

m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180, 180, 30), labels = [0,0,0,1])
m.drawcoastlines()

x,y = m(lon, lat)
m.plot(x, y, 'o', c= range(amount), markersize=4,zorder=8, markerfacecolor='#424FA4',markeredgecolor="none", alpha=0.33)

plt.colorbar(label="Amount")
plt.clim(0, 6000)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some statistic computing that produces mappable values for the colorbar. For example, replace the line:

```
m.plot(...)
```

with

```
m.hexbin(x, y, bins='log', gridsize=30, alpha=0.5, edgecolors='gray')
```

It will show the number of occurrences better than using heatmap.

If you want to take the mass into consideration, you can use:

```
m.hexbin(x,y, bins='log', C=df['mass_g'].values, gridsize=30, alpha=0.5, edgecolors='gray')
```

You will get an output plot like this:

[image]

Hope this helps.